# How does Pysnmp load third-party mib libraries?

Tags: pysnmp

I downloaded the mib library on cisco's official website. The mib files are suffixed with .my, but I don't know how to use pysnmp to reference these mib files.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just give pysnmp a [path](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/mib-tweaks.html#custom-asn-1-mib-path) to the location of your MIBs (as well as the base MIBs they import), pysnmp should be able to consume these `.my` files:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
    getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
           CommunityData('public'),
           UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
           ContextData(),
           ObjectType(
               ObjectIdentity(
                   'IF-MIB', 'ifInOctets', 1).addAsn1MibSource(
                        'file:///home/user/mibs/',                                                                'http://mibs.snmplabs.com/asn1/@mib@')))
```

)